# Is there a reason why Rails' Core Extensions haven't been incorporated into Ruby lang?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just curious, if there is a particular reason why some of Rails' convenient Core Extensions (e.g. - `#blank?`, `#present?`, `#exclude?`, and perhaps even String-only utilities like `#truncate`) haven't been ported directly into the Ruby language?

I understand that methods like `#blank?` exist almost solely for cosmetics, and yeah, there are the ActiveSupport gems, but it just feels so dirty to write lines like `if !include?(a)`. Perhaps the Ruby-lang-powers-at-hand don't merge in anything cosmetic (similar to the [Rails contribution policy](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13771#issuecomment-32746700)), and only support the further, slightly monopolistic, solidification of existing code? Alternatively there may just be a lack of man-power in moving it out to a C-extension, being an open-source project... but I highly doubt that.

Comment: You should probably direct this question at the Ruby maillist, or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manpower prioritization.

Ruby 2.x has these major improvements:

- Optimization e.g. garbage collection, regexp engine, method caching.
- Upgrade primitive-equivalents, e.g. Unicode strings, rational numbers.
- Update libraries, e.g. psych, rake, rdoc, gem, minitest.
- Improve debugging capabilities, e.g. object allocation tracing, exception causes.
- Improve developer semantics, e.g. method prepend, refinements, keyword args.

These are currently more valuable than adding methods like `#blank?` to the core language.